# What artifacts to ignore from version control in a .net core application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn to build a web application using .net core, mvc x and csharp.  I am using visual studio code in OS X.

Here are the files and folders inside the freshly generated project directory:

```
Controllers
Dockerfile
Program.cs
Properties
README.md
Startup.cs
Views
appsettings.json
bower.json
bundleconfig.json
project.json
web.config
wwwroot
```

I think the following should be excluded and what else?

- bin/
- obj/
- .vscode
- wwwroot

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly exclude `.vscode`. It's convenient to share your tasks and debug profiles with others.
This is my .gitignore

```
node_modules/
**/bin/
**/obj/
**/*.VC.db*   #vscode local database files
.vs/          #your friends who use visual studio
project.lock.json
TestResults/      
.idea.*        #ever heard of Jetbrains Rider?
**/appsettings.production.json
npm-debug.*
```